# summarize data by multiple dimensions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a news feed application that pulls in data in JSON format from another site. I don't really care about the actual articles, I just need to summarize various metadata to be stored for later use in performance evaluations. The source array looks like the following:

```
let articles = [
    {id: "0",title: "article 1",tags: ["110"],source: "Company A", countries:["USA","CAN"]},
    {id: "1",title: "article 2",tags: ["120","160","100"],source: "Company B", countries:["USA","CHN"]},
    {id: "2",title: "article 3",tags: ["130","150"],source: "Company C", countries:["USA"]},
    {id: "3",title: "article 4",tags: ["140","120","110","130"],source: "Company A", countries:["JPN","IRE"]},
    {id: "4",title: "article 5",tags: ["110","130"],source: "Company C", countries:["SWE"]},
  ]
```

I need to count the number of occurrences for tags and countries by source, but also by tag. My desired output is the following:

```
let output = [
    {source: "Company A",tags:[{code:"110",count:2},{code:"140",count:1},{code:"120",count:1},{code:"130",count:1}],countries:[{code:"USA",count:1},{code:"CAN",count:1},{code:"JPN",count:1},{code:"IRE",count:1}]},
    {source: "Company B",tags:[{code:"120",count:1},{code:"160",count:1},{code:"100",count:1}],countries:[{code:"USA",count:1},{code:"CHN",count:1}]},
    {source: "Company C",tags:[{code:"110",count:2},{code:"130",count:2},{code:"150",count:1}],countries:[{code:"USA",count:1},{code:"SWE",count:1}]}
  ]

let output2 = [
    {tag:"110",sources:[{source:"Company A",count:2},{source:"Company C",count:1}],countries:[{country:"USA",count:1},{country:"CAN",count:1},{country:"SWE",count:1}]},
    {tag:"120",sources:[{source:"Company A",count:1},{source:"Company B",count:1}],countries:[{country:"USA",count:1},{country:"CHN",count:1},{country:"JPN",count:1},{country:"IRE",count:1}]},
    {tag:"130",sources:[{source:"Company A",count:1},{source:"Company C",count:1}],countries:[{country:"USA",count:1},{country:"SWE",count:1}]},
    {tag:"140",sources:[{source:"Company A",count:1}],countries:[{country:"JPN",count:1},{country:"IRE",count:1}]},
    {tag:"150",sources:[{source:"Company C",count:1}],countries:[{country:"USA",count:1}]},
    {tag:"160",sources:[{source:"Company B",count:1}],countries:[{country:"USA",count:1},{country:"CHN",count:1}]},
    {tag:"100",sources:[{source:"Company B",count:1}],countries:[{country:"USA",count:1},{country:"CHN",count:1}]}
]
```

I'm not sure what the best way to proceed is. I had 3 sets built, one for tags, countries, and sources. my thought was to build an object from the sets, then iterate over each item and add to the count for each category. Scalability is one of the things I'm concerned about since the source of the articles can be anywhere from 100 items to 5000 items depending on when I run the script. The number of tags per article can be 1-10+ and countries can be 1-50+ from some of the data I've reviewed.

```
tags = new Set();
countries = new Set();
sources = new Set();

articles.forEach(item =>{
   item.tags.forEach(element =>{
      tags.add(element);
    })
})

articles.forEach(item =>{
    item.countries.forEach(element =>{
        countries.add(element);
    })
})

articles.forEach(item =>{
    sources.add(item.source);
})
```

UPDATED: current solution via caTS. I modified to create the 2nd desired output. It's more of an annoyance than a performance issue, but I would also like to sort the final output by tag so it's in number order. I can't seem to find the right spot to add that part in.

```
//-----By Tag------//

articles.forEach((a) => {
    a.tags.forEach((tag) => {
        if (!tags.has(tag)) tags.set(tag, { sources: new Map(), countries: new Map() });
    
        tags.get(tag).sources.set(a.source, (tags.get(tag).sources.get(a.source) ?? 0) + 1);
    
        a.countries.forEach((c) => {
            tags.get(tag).countries.set(c, (tags.get(tag).countries.get(c) ?? 0) + 1);
        });
    });
});

const result = Array.from(tags)
    .map(([tag, { sources, countries }]) => ({
        tag,
        sources: Array.from(sources).map(([source, count]) => ({ source, count })),
        countries: Array.from(countries).map(([country, count]) => ({ country, count })),
    }));

console.log(result);

//-----By Source------//

articles.forEach((a) => {
    if (!sources.has(a.source)) sources.set(a.source, { tags: new Map(), countries: new Map() });
    
        a.tags.forEach((b) => {
            sources.get(a.source).tags.set(b, (sources.get(a.source).tags.get(b) ?? 0) + 1);
        });

        a.countries.forEach((c) => {
            sources.get(a.source).countries.set(c, (sources.get(a.source).countries.get(c) ?? 0) + 1);
    });
});

const result2 = Array.from(sources)
    .map(([source, { tags, countries }]) => ({
        source,
        tags: Array.from(tags).map(([tags, count]) => ({ tags, count })),
        countries: Array.from(countries).map(([country, count]) => ({ country, count })),
    }));

console.log(result2);
```

Comment: I came up with [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx8Zbm)...

Comment: yeah that works. I modified your code to do the 2nd output, by source: